# Embed link to an embedded file

Tags: pdf, embedding

I am embedding a PDF file inside my LaTeX-generated PDF file using embedfile:

```
\usepackage{embedfile}
\embedfile{myfile.pdf}
```

I would like to also insert a link that the user can click on to open the attachment.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Related question: [How do I make an attached file display like a link?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/how-do-i-make-an-attached-file-display-like-a-link).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [`navigator`](http://ctan.org/pkg/navigator) package instead of [`embedfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) - both packages are [quite similar to use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file/13218#13218) (the macro to embed a file is called `\embeddedfile` instead of `\embedfile`), but [`navigator`](http://ctan.org/pkg/navigator) additionally supports the `\openfilelink` command which creates links to embedded files:

```
\openfilelink [<appearence options>]{<file name>}[<page number to open>]{<link text>}
```

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{navigator}
\embeddedfile{myfile}{myfile.pdf}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Demonstration:} \openfilelink{myfile.pdf}{Link to the embedded file \texttt{myfile.pdf}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked really well. Thanks. Required that I get navigator.tex, yax.tex and texapi.tex, but it was worth it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on TeXLive2012, XeTeX.

Comment: @Adobe The MWE above works fine for me with XeLaTeX (using TeX Live 2012). Do you get any error messages when trying to compile the document?

Comment: @diabonas: Thanks. I tried again: doesn't produce any error messages. Doesn't work in okular and evince. But works in Adobe Reader after *2* clicks.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a link, use the package `attachfile` instead of `embedfile`. The default behavior of a file attached with `\attachfile{filename}` is to display an icon, but `\textattachfile{filename}{<text>}` will turn `<text>` into a link to your embedded file.

`attachfile` works well, I've been using it for years.

EDIT:

Regarding your trouble with a printout: The manual of attachfile tells you that the boolean option `print=true` will never print, unless you tell your pdf-viewer to do that -- and most of them, including Acrobat, won't, anyway what you do. You asked for clickable links, not for printouts. . .

But of course it is possible to have all the text printed on paper, e.g. like that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc, attachfile}


\newlength{\Urlname}
\newcommand{\doubleprint}[1]{\setlength{\Urlname}{\widthof{#1}}}
\newcommand{\textattachfileandprintout}[2]{%
\textattachfile[color=0 0 0]{#1}{#2}\doubleprint{#2}\hspace{-\Urlname}#2}
\begin{document}

\textattachfileandprintout{filename}{linktext}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\textattachfile{}{}` use the `\textattachfileandprintout` or define a shorter command!

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: Argh! Two problems with attachfile. Problem #1 - the text is yellow with Acrobat Viewer. Problem #2 - the text is invisible on Apple's Preview. Any thoughts?

Comment: @vy32 To solve your first problem, you can say `\textattachfile[color=0 0 0]{filename}{<text>}` to change the text color to black.

Comment: The best solution has been suggested here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/how-do-i-make-an-attached-file-display-like-a-link/19161#19161

Comment: In contrast to `navigator` and `hypgotoe`, this solution also works for bibtex and within SumatraPDF.