# Link to and attached/embedded file?

Tags: xetex, embedding, attachfile

I'm using XeTeX and I'd like to have a link to an attached/embedded file.

There's a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19025/embed-link-to-an-embedded-file) -- but it doesn't work for me: I'm using TeXlive2012.

As I understand it the best bet is to use `attachfile2` package.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xetex]{attachfile2}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Test!}

Link: see \textattachfile{lagrange.png}{this citation}.

\end{document}
```

I can right-click on a link and save the file -- but it would be much nicer if I could just click the file and let the OS open it with the default application.

**Edit**:

If one attachs file with `attachfile2` -- it behaves differenctly on different readers.

If one embeds a file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{navigator}
\embeddedfile{lagrange}{lagrange.png}
\begin{document}
I attached a file -- called \texttt{lagrange.png}
\end{document}
```

some users won't find it.

So the most stable way is to put files to embed in a special dir, say in `flz`, and distribute the zip folder:

```
.
├── 1.pdf
└── flz
    └── lagrange.png
```

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
See \href{run:flz/lagrange.png}{here}.
\end{document}
```

Then it's clickable and stable.

**Edit 2**:

I'm using `attachfile2` as posted in the first MWE.

Comment: It opens on double-click in Adobe Readers and asks to save on double-click in SumatraPDF.

Comment: That's strange: I get no effect in okular and evince. Evince said: `Couldn't open attachment “lagrange.png”: Failed to execute child process "eog" (Permission denied)`. It turns out that `eog` is an image viewer -- `eye of gnome` -- and I have it installed.

Comment: It opens on double-click in Adobe Reader for me to.

Comment: I'm not really clear on this: are you saying it's a viewer issue or something else?

Comment: @JosephWright: if one attaches with `navigator` it is not seen on some readers at all. If one attaches with `attachfile2` it behaves a little bit differently across readers, but still accessible. If one carries file then `href` always work.

Comment: @Adobe `hyperref` is only linking to a file, whereas both `attachefile2` and `navigator` are actually embedding the file. The latter process sounds very much dependent on the viewer, and that sounds like what you're seeing.

Comment: @JosephWright: Yep, that's what we see. But that doesn't meen that it is *imposible* to embed file into a pdf in a "stable way". Although that could be a case.

Comment: @Adobe I'm afraid it does. Different viewers implement different parts of the PDF spec in different ways. Provided they deal correctly with the display of 'static' information (text, _etc._) in the way specified in the PDF standard, that variability is not an error.

Comment: I think this is a viewer issue, so it's really 'off topic' (or certainly not answerable in a positive sense) for us.