# Are there any ways to embed LaTeX source code from a PDF file

Tags: tex-core, mathtools, embedfile

I want to the tex files from PDF files. 
I have the PDF files that I get in Internet and have a lot of mathematics,  so I want to convert PDF files into tex files. 
I researched in these forum, and  following links may be related ,but I couldnt understand clearly.
[Is there some way to embed LaTeX source code in a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/is-there-some-way-to-embed-latex-source-code-in-a-pdf-file)
[Embed link to an embedded file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19025/embed-link-to-an-embedded-file)

Please teach me are there any ways, or teach me how to use.

Thank you.

January,3rd i added.
What i want is OCR,not embedded. i want pdf or images to detect the text words into tex.

Comment: you can't extract actual tex code from a pdf file unless the originator has explicitly included it.  the first question that you cite tells how to embed such a file, but you want the opposite.

Comment: `attachfile` package perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this package 
http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/embedall/embedall.pdf

who use the embedfiles package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{embedall}

\begin{document}

test

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this could solve the problem. The OP wants to extract the code from the pdf output (to save retyping time, for example).