# Copy pastable code in tex

Tags: spacing, copy-paste, accsupp

I have XML code which I need to copy paste. 
Here's is the code

```
<joint name="joint1" type="continuous">
  <parent link="link1"/>
  <child link="link2"/>
  <origin xyz="5 3 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</joint>
```

I have used accsup to make it copy/paste-able as follows:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
upquote=true,
columns=fullflexible,
literate={\ }{{\copyablespace}}1
}

\usepackage[space=true]{accsupp}
% requires the latest version of package accsupp
\newcommand{\copyablespace}{
\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,ActualText=00A0}
\ %
\EndAccSupp{}
}
```

I am new to LaTex and am not sure what exactly is happening here. But the `BeginAccSupp` part is replacing each space by 3 spaces in the pdf and as well when I copy paste.

```
<joint   name="joint1"   type="continuous">
    <parent   link="link1"/>
    <child   link="link2"/>
    <origin   xyz="5   3   0"   rpy="0   0   0"   />
</joint>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit !:** After @Phelype Oleinik's solution, the PDF looks fine, also the indentation after I copy/paste is good, but the spaces in between the line are still the same

```
<joint   name="joint1"   type="continuous">
 <parent   link="link1"/>
 <child   link="link2"/>
 <origin   xyz="5   3   0"   rpy="0   0   0"   />
</joint>
```

**Edit 2:** A hack that works (not for the string spaces though) is replacing the spaces with tabs in the `{lstlisting}`.

So the code in tex looks like:

```
<joint  name="joint1" type="continuous">
  <parent   link="link1"/>
  <child    link="link2"/>
  <origin   xyz="5 3 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</joint>
```

And the copy/pasted code looks liḱe:

```
<joint name="joint1"   type="continuous">
 <parent link="link1"/>
 <child link="link2"/>
 <origin xyz="5   3   0"   rpy="0   0   0"   />
</joint
```

But not sure if I want to go with this hack.

Comment: You have spurious spaces in your `\copyablespace` macro. If you put a `%` right after each line of the macro the problem should vanish. Use this: `\newcommand{\copyablespace}{%
\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,ActualText=00A0}%
\ %
\EndAccSupp{}%
}`

Comment: Thanks! Now the PDF looks fine but the copy pasted code is still the same. BTW what exactly does `%` do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Missing end-of-line protection is a common error.

Comment: Be careful to add `%` correctly: `\newcommand{\copyablespace}{%`, `\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,ActualText=00A0}%` and `\EndAccSupp{}%`

Comment: is it something to do with `unicode` in `\BeginAccSupp`? I could not paste anything after the 1st space without unicode, but with it, each space is replaced by 3.

Comment: FWIW, I get the correct spaces if I remove the `literate` option.

Comment: If I remove literate option, there's not indentation after pasting the code.

Comment: @harsh When TeX read a *single* new line, it interprets it as a space (that's why you can write a paragraph in multiple lines of code). This happens inside your macro. The `%` char is added to the end of the line to make TeX ignore what comes after, including the new line. For a more lengthy explanation see the first part of my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407620/134574).

Comment: Why don't you embedd an xml-file with your code to the PDF and refer to it in the text? There are some packages, like attachfile, attachfile2, embedfile. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19025/4736 how to do that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was (maybe partially) solved in the comments