# Detect and act on tampering/re-printing of PDF

Tags: printing, embedding, adobe, security, interaction

Is there a way to make a LaTeX-produced PDF file appear wildly different if someone has modified it (i.e. by opening it in a PDF reader application, and using the "Print to PDF" feature)?

In short, I have some large LaTeX documents that have some degree of "interactive" functionality, mainly by [embedding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19025/embed-link-to-an-embedded-file) small video clips (i.e. `mp4`) and GPG-signed tarballs that contain important files.

On more than one occasion, people have passed these files along for presentations, and then embarassment/issues arise when people keep trying to double-click and open linked files embedded within the document, to no avail. Every time this happens, it's due to someone modifying the document (typically by printing it via Firefox or a scripted tool that adds an unwanted watermark), which ends up stripping the embedded attachments and causing some interactive functionality to be stripped/disabled too.

Is there some way to embed some sort of overlay or something that would make the document hideous (i.e. giant red diagnonal "warning" or "Ted stop watermarking your name on other people's documents" message on each page) that only renders if someone re-prints the document?

Comment: You need Adobe Acrobat Professional (the expensive one) to add security.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Would something simpler be possible with LaTeX? I'm mainly interested in the appearance changing if the PDF is "re-rendered" rather than locking it down. Also, I want people on Linux platforms to be able to read the document (2000+ people read these, and next to none of them use MS products).