# Embed text in pgfplots or tikz generated pdf files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

I generate data plots in my LaTeX documentation using a combination of [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) and [`pgfplots`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/). Many of the plots are generated using script files which can also include the raw data if data is being plotted. Is there anyway to embed the script files in the plot itself (these could be `pgfplots` scripts or python code etc)?

The idea is that if someone obtains the pdf file they can extract the script and/or data that actually generated the plot and therefore will be able to reproduce the figure themselves and have at hand the original data that was used.

I saw the message on [`pdfcomment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex) and it looks very promising. Would `pdfcomment` be a good way to embed text in plots or are other other possible approaches?

A comment on those who might suggest why not just supply the raw LaTeX file. These documents get submitted to journals, archives (e.g. [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/)) and other repositories where the raw LaTeX file cannot usually be included with the submission.

Comment: Maybe you can embed your code as a pdf file something like this question [how-do-i-make-an-attached-file-display-like-a-link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/how-do-i-make-an-attached-file-display-like-a-link)?

Comment: I don't understand the comment about the arXiv.  If the LaTeX file was uploaded, anyone can access it.

Comment: have you looked at these [attach+file+to+pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=attach+file+to+pdf)

Comment: Rely to arXiv comment: arXiv doesn't give you access to the original LaTeX file only the finished pdf file.

Comment: Reply to cmhughes, I hadn't come across attachfile.sty before, I think that's exactly what I want. Many thanks.

Comment: Reply to percusse: Thank you that link, again that the kind of thing I was looking for,

Comment: @rhody No problem, if you want to reply to a specific user just do what I did in the start of this comment. That would ping the respective user.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at `\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}`, and especially its `clickable coords` key. The idea is to click into the pdf and get a popup with addition meta data for single coordinates -- and the coordinate values as well. Might be enough for most users if you have an e-document

Comment: On the arXiv, from the "Download" list select "Other formats" and then "Download source".  That gives you exactly what the author uploaded.  So if you include the data as an extra file there, anyone can access it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of existing packages that can be used to attach data (in the form of files) to a pdf file generated from a LaTeX document. [pdfcomment](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) is a package that can be used to annotate a LaTeX file with user annotation and comments. The other possibility includes the packages [attachfile](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile) and [attachfile2](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2). Files can be attached to specific points in the PDF file using these packages. Thus a graph can have the raw data attached to it. In the final pdf, attachments are indicated with icons and double clicking on the icon will bring up the appropriate external application to view the attached file.