# pdflatex + java applet?

Tags: pdftex, java

I am writing lecture notes in Euclidean/Noneuclidean geometry, see [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1577084/m427/m427.html).
The lecture 10 is about geometric constructions, where I use some java applets for construction.

So far I made a hyperlink from `.pdf` file to `.html` file, which contains the links to all constructions. But I would like to keep everything in one pdf-file.
(So one could download single file and do everything offline.)

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to keep in the PDF? Do you want something attach or embed? Then read the manuals of `attachfile2` and `embedfile`, both part of the `oberdiek` bundle.

Comment: @Speravir, I guess I can attach few files to my .pdf file. Does one of these packages makes possible to open one of attached .html files in a browser?

Comment: I do not know, but believe there was already a question here on TeX.SX, look for yourself: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=embedfile+attachfile+attachfile2.

Comment: I think this approach is better: Put all files into a directory or in an additonal subdirectory. Let all students start the HTML file, where you link to PDF and the java applets. Pack in a ZIP file or similar.

Comment: Ah, question, I thought of, found: [How do I make an attached file display like a link?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/how-do-i-make-an-attached-file-display-like-a-link).