# attaching a file to latex

Tags: attachfile

I have a "trilogi" simulation software file. Consider it as a file of random simulation software. I want to embed it in pdf document at the place of my choice so that if I click on it in pdf document,it opens. How should I do it?
My simple working program is as given below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{memoir}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\section*{\textcolor{red}{Introduction}}
Control engineering has evolved over time. In the past humans were the main method for controlling a system. More recently electricity has been used for control and control d
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `attachfile`package, I have been using it for instance here: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2488 (Check the definition of `\file` there)

Comment: I understand the attach file package in the sense that I can embed pdf files. But how to embed other files. Following is how I embed pdf files What change do I do know from here \usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hypgotoe}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\embedfile{midsem.pdf}

Comment: @shivam No, you can embed any file!

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How do I make an attached file display like a link?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17926/5764); [Embed link to an embedded file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19025/5764)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a short example, how to do it with `attachfile`. It attaches the source code of the current file to the PDF and creates a clickable link. Adobe Reader/Acrobat has a tab, where it shows all attachments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}  

\textattachfile{\jobname.tex}{\textcolor{blue}{\LaTeX\ Sourcecode}}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]