# How do I make an attached non-pdf file display like a link?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, external-files, embedding, attachfile

I'm embedding an external file in my pdf with `\usepackage{attachfile2}` and `\textattachfile[color=1 1 1]{description}{file.txt}`. How can I make the text look the same as it would if I had used the hyperref package and done something like

```
\label{here}%
\rlap{\hyperref{here}{\phantom{description}}}%
\textattachfile[color=0 0 0]{description}{file.txt}
```

?

I'm looking for something that includes the non-printing border, but only opens the file when clicked.  I suppose I'd be ok with some hacky code that modifies the internals of hyperref or attachfile2.  (I haven't figured out myself how to redefine `\Hy@StartlinkName` to use, e.g., `user` instead of `goto link`, because I don't know what `/A` and `/Subtype` to pass to user.  I also haven't figured out how to modify the internals of attachfile2 to behave more like hyperref.)

Note: the solution to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17926/2066) only works for embedded pdf files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a link to an embedded file using the JavaScript function [`exportDataObject`](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/importing-and-exporting-pdf-file-attachments-acrobat-javascript). The following code creates a new command `\embeddedfilelink{<file>}{<text>}` that creates a link to an embedded file specified by its file name with the given link text. The code is taken from [`hypgotoe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypgotoe) and modified to create a JavaScript action instead of a GoToE action.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% How do I make an attached non-pdf file display like a link?
% (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230581)
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\embeddedfilelink}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \pdfstartlink
      attr{%
        \Hy@setpdfborder
        \ifx\@pdfhighlight\@empty
        \else
          /H\@pdfhighlight
        \fi
        \ifx\@filebordercolor\relax
        \else
          /C[\@filebordercolor]%
        \fi
      }%
      user{%
       /Subtype/Link%
       /A<<%
         /Type/Action%
         /S/JavaScript%
         /JS(this.exportDataObject({cName: "#1", nLaunch: 2}))%
       >>%
      }%
      \relax
    \Hy@colorlink\@filebordercolor#2%
    \close@pdflink
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\embedfile{file.txt}

\begin{document}
\embeddedfilelink{file.txt}{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: appearance of link to embedded file]

Clicking the link opens the embedded file after confirming the obligatory security warning

[image: Adobe Reader security warning when trying to open an embedded file]

Note that this solution only works with readers supporting JavaScript, which probably few viewers other than Adobe Reader/Acrobat do.

Comment: Good one..... :-)

Comment: Gives me the error: `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color '0 .5 .5'`