# How to embedded source code on-demand into PDF?

Tags: pdf, sourcecode, syntax-highlighting, interaction

I wondered if its possible to embed source code of some software you are writing about into the PDF but not displayed by default. E.g. you have a long script I would be nice if the user/reader could click on a link if he needs details, and see the source code of that script.

Best would be if this can be rendered with syntax highlighting (by listings or minted package).

So far I am only aware of either use ECMAscript (which seems not supported by latex) or by OCG layers, as tooltips. For both I am unsure if they support syntax highlighting.

As a workaround I would do it as in the old days with an appendix and hyperref to it.

Do you have any better suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you may embed your source code as a file *in* the pdf. I'm using usually the package [attachfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile), but there are some more, the [embedfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) package e.g. or [attachfile2](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2).

Using attachfile I'm printing an icon into the margin and explain in the PDF text that clicking on the symbol will provide the attached file.

Comment: Please note that there is a difference between attaching and embedding at the PDF file level, see the documentation of the packages.

Comment: @TeXnician the documentation of attachfile says "This package defines an \attachfile command that lets you attach arbitrary
files to a pdf document. These files are embedded right in the pdf
file, so they get transmitted along with it." That sounds like there is no difference?

Comment: @lucidbrot You need to read the right documentation (attachfile2/embedfile): "The PDF format ([3]) allows the inclusion of fies inside the PDF document. The
included fies can be bound to an annotation on a page. Or they can be recorded
in a sorted list of embedded fies. The packages attachfie or attachfie2 follow the
fist approach, package embedfie uses the latter method." Of course that does not explain the technical details, but it gives the right hint.

Comment: Yes this is quite cool. Unfortunately not all PDF readers can handle it, e.g. I tried to open with firefox builtin reader and no action took place. But with other readers I had success, very neat. Thank all of you so much.

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician, do you have a suggested reading if I'm interested in the technical difference between the two? Can't you just link to an embedded file as well? (as long as it's a pdf format at least)

Comment: @math Pdf.js is no real PDF reader which focuses on advanced PDF support, it is a good viewer though.

Comment: @lucidbrot If I remember correctly you'll find the PDF specification online which should contain these details. Concerning the linking I think they are quite equivalent.

Comment: @TeXnician [Thanks, found it!](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) under 12.5.6.15 and 7.11.4  I am still unsure about the differences, but it seems like file attachment annotations are meant for linking to additional reading/data included whereas embedding is for images that are then referenced within the pdf. I believe that the annotiations are just a redirection to the embedding though: "A file attachment annotation contains a reference to a file [...] see Embedded File Streams"

Comment: @lucidbrot Sound quite right. It's been a while since I opened this document ;)

Comment: I also found that the embedfile package seems to better interact with the hyperref and hypgotoe package, to preserve the specified link-color. ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/how-do-i-make-an-attached-file-display-like-a-link )